# AIX 6.1 Subscription

Tags: aix, ibm

I have few questions regarding AIX subscription, I know its not programming but I really need to get an answer from someone with experience.

1. AIX subscription means: we would be able to update our current version with any available updates (patches, fixes, service packs...etc.) that are pushed by IBM.
2. AIX subscription means: we would be able to upgrade (optionally) for the current version 6.1 to a newer version (say 7.0).
3. After the 3 years warranty if we don't pay the yearly fees we would stop receiving any updates or the ability to upgrade.
4. After the 3 years warranty if we don't pay the yearly fees we would be still able to use the machines with the latest build we installed using the old subscription with no issues ??(the AIX will continue running and the license will not expire).

I tried contacting the retailer but his experience with AIX's warranty and subscriptions is no better than mine, I thought I would find more experience here,so any little info is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Answer (score 0):

This is really something that you need to talk to IBM sales about.  If your retailer is unable to answer the question, I'm sure you could go to IBM's site for your country and get in touch with someone who could help you.